# Get user's response for beforeunload event if the user leaves the domain

Tags: angularjs, events, browser, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

I have an AngularJS app and use the following code to let the user confirm if s/he really wants to leave the page and might loose unsaved data:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
    return 'Do you really want to leave?'
});

window.addEventListener('unload', function (e) {
    console.log('unload');
    myRestService.close();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

This works well and the browser displays the message box where the user has to decide to leave or to stay on the page. However, if the user really wants to leave the page, I have to make a call to a rest backend. For that I thought that I can also register for the unload event that is fired when the user actually leaves the back. That works if the user reloads the back or navigates to a different url within the app. However, the event is not fired, or at least I can't see it, when the user navigates to anthoer page or closes the browser.

How can I also catch these events and make sure that my rest call still goes through?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function before tab close like this:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (arg) {
  $scope.onclose();
}
```

and now you can all your rest api in close function

for more detail and other methods follow [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/nnse0g/confirmation-on-leaving-the-current-page-in-an-angular-js-app)

Comment: Well this will be called also if the user decides to stay on the page. Or won't it?

Comment: no it won't. It is a Confirmation on Leaving the Current Page .But if user is not leaving the page then you can do something else to make rest call like using a idle  method,or use timeout or you can make call on any other event etc..

Comment: Hmm, sorry I still don't get it exactly. In the code above, I see that I call onclose when the user is about leaving the page. But I only want to call my REST API when the user answers the confirmation window that will then show up with YES. If the user stays on the page, I don't want to make a REST call. Maybe you can provide a more complete example?